# Trying to get lookup field value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a custom object named CPQ_Request_for_Proposal__c, which has a lookup(Text) value for Account__c.

I'm trying to code a button which will use the value of Account__c to get actual Account object.  The first alert() comes up.  However, my code keeps returning **"Unexpected Identifier"** before the second `alert()` appears.  I'm new to using JavaScript in a Salesforce context.  I'm sure I'm doing something simple wrong, but I haven't been able to figure it out after searching for an answer for a while.  What am I doing wrong in my code?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}

// Visual hint to the user that the processing has started this.disabled = true; 
this.className = "btnDisabled";

var clientSite = new sforce.SObject("Client_Site__c");  
var rfpId = '{!CPQ_Request_for_Proposal__c.Id}';   
clientSite.RequestForProposal__c
= '{!CPQ_Request_for_Proposal__c.Id}';

alert ( 'RFP Id = ' + rfpId );

var accountId = '';

var accountId = '{!CPQ_Request_for_Proposal__c.Account__c}';

alert ( 'accountId = ' + accountId );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to use the **Select Field Type** and **Insert Field** pickers.  That yielded the following syntax, which works:

```
var accountId = '{!CPQ_Request_for_Proposal__c.AccountId__c}';
```

This is interesting (to me, at least) in that there is no AccountId__c field on the CPQ_Request_for_Proposal__c object.

Comment: Yes AccountId__c can only be found in the dropdown that contains merge fields..while creating a custom button.

Answer (score 3):

When you code merge fields into JavaScript, you should use JSENCODE to avoid quotes and apostrophes from breaking your code. It works like this:

```
var x = "{!JSENCODE(Field)}";
```

It would seem to me that you're getting the name of the account, and that name contains a quoting character, such as "Bob's Hardware and BBQ."